# Get the projection coordinates of three-dimensional points on the scene3D in qt3d, and develop tools is QML and qt3d

Tags: qt, qml

I get a Point name `A (a,b,c)` in the three-dimensional zoom Relative to the world coordinate system, and the camera view center is always (0,0,0) of World coordinate system， how to get the projection coordinates `(X,Y)` of A when a moving camera, I'm a new learner of QML

[image]

Comment: i need get the 2D point of A's projection on the scene3D screen

Comment: Please clarify the question and provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run and test it.

Comment: Isn't that simply the 2D mouse position on the screen (offset by widget offset, etc.)?

Comment: @FlorianBlume  yeah! it's what you mean,  the scene3D is a QML widget type. I need obtain the simply 2D mouse position on the widget.  Excited！ I have solve this problem by this http://webglfactory.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-convert-world-to-screen.html

Comment: I'm glad you solved it. But do you actually need any computation for that? I think there are ways to obtain the mouse position from Qt simply, no need to project the 3D point.